# Tailwind styling not working after navigating from another page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, styling

I am building a site using Next.JS and tailwind.

On the homepage, the content in the wrapping divs in the project section displays in the centre.

However, when I navigate to my about page using the navbar link, and then return to the homepage, the content in the divs no longer displays in the centre (it displays to the left). This issue is not solved unless I refresh the page.

Any ideas how I can solve this issue please?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing routes to your about page and back, the class of the child element under projects changes from `col-span-3 content-center place-items-center md:mx-40` to `ProjectSection_proj1Left__CTWEv`. I guess that is why it breaks. So check if you set this somewhere (maybe even by accident).